# A bunch of incoming Mythbuntu Questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Over the next week we'll be importing a large amount of Mythbuntu questions from their FAQ. Due to this import we will have a lot of questions that require cleanup in both formatting and tagging.

Also, some of the content was originally written for 9.10 - those running Mythbuntu, or willing to setup a machine for testing, we'd appreciate testing of these instructions in current releases and updating the answers, where needed, to make them current.

I'll update this post with more information as it becomes available.

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=751719

---

So basically at UDS Jorge and I were approached by the Mythbuntu team to help them out importing this content into AU so that it can be updated and maintained. We need to:

- Import the content, much of it is out of date and needs help, but right now it's locked in forum posts that no one can improve, so sucking them in is needed.
- Edit and improve them.
- Update them to newer versions of Ubuntu if possible.
- The mythbuntu folks will end up closing that thread and marking it as out of date, regardless we do need to link back to the forum thread as we *must* cite our sources.
- If something is obviously horrible and we bring it in then flag it or just leave it to die on the old thread, most of the hardware ones will likely not be useful, it could be that destroying the information is actually the best thing to do. :)
- Some of the users will be new and will need editing/site usage help, so please be helpful to them.

Feel free to start now, or at least discussing this in meta now, Jorge is planning on starting importing the easier/complete ones in a few hours.

Comment: ...and remember: screenshots are worth a thousand words (doesn't count toward the character limit :) the thousand words, that is...)

Answer (score 3):

[It was brought up in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2334409#2334409) that we might need to consider some tag synouns.

primarily, perhaps make [mythtv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mythtv) be a synoun of [mythbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mythbuntu)? Upvote this if you agree, downvote otherwise. But if you downvote, please leave a comment stating why you think this isn't needed! :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure about this - but it may be the case. While Mythbuntu is using Mythtv as an upstream it's, from my understanding, heavily modified. So Mythbuntu -> MythTV, MythTV != Mythbuntu